# UPDATED. f:link.page sometimes creates links in the wrong language

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

**Update:**
When creating a new translation for a site and call it, realURL caches the path. When you then change the title of this site a new path is generated.
The old path is still in the cache and so both path works.

Is it somehow possible to force realURL to only output the new paths, but keep the old paths so that they still work?

**Old Question:**

---

I found a strange behavior of my menu. Sometimes it creates links with the wrong links. To explain it I will create an example:

```
Lets say I have following sitestructure in defaultlanguge:
/the-thing/home

So for english(UK) I have the following URL:
/uk/the-thing/home

But for german I have:
/de/das-ding/home  (the-thing is translated to german)
```

But sometimes `f:link.page` and `f:link.typolink` creates the german link with the default-structurenames. For the example above that means `/de/the-thing/home`.

This link will **not** work when I am logged in in the backend, but when I am not logged in in the backend the link **works**.

This not only happens in the menu, so I will not post the menu code, as it is a bit complicated. But I will post this:

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{langele.language.url}" additionalParams="&L={langele.language.language}">{langele.language.languagename}</f:link.typolink>

Example values:
{langele.language.url}: 11 (page_uid)
{langele.language.language}: 2 (sys_language_uid)
{langele.language.languagename}: Just a textfield
```

This code is in a contentelement that creates links to other languages and is placed in the default language.

The languages are in a singletree and the translated pages have just another page title. I do not use Alternative Navigation Title. I use realURL. My realURL config is not much modified (Most of the config is for extensions, 404 handling):

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']=array (
  '_DEFAULT' => 
  array (
    'init' => 
    array (
      'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
      'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
    ),
    'pagePath' => 
    array (
      'rootpage_id' => '1',
    ),
    'fileName' => 
    array (
      'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
      'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
      'index' => 
      array (
        'print' => 
        array (
          'keyValues' => 
          array (
            'type' => 98,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'preVars' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' => 
        array (
            'ch' => 1,
            'uk' => 2,
            'au' => 3,
            'at' => 4,
            'ca' => 5,
            'hr' => 6,
            'cy' => 7,
            'fi' => 10,
            'de' => 12,
            'hu' => 13,
            'it' => 15,
            'sa' => 16,
            'nl' => 18,
            'no' => 19,
            'sg' => 20,
            'es' => 23,
            'se' => 24,
            'tr' => 26,
            'ae' => 27,
            'us' => 28
        ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
      ),
    ),
    'postVarSets' => 
    array (
      '_DEFAULT' => 
      array (
        'news' => array(
            array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
            ),
            array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
            ),
            array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'title',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                    'strtolower' => 1,
                                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                            ),
                            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                            'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                            'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                            'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                            'autoUpdate' => 1,
                            'expireDays' => 180,
                    ),
            ),
        ),
        'collection' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_mystuff_collection[mystuff]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'tx_mystuff_domain_model_mystuff',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'name',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                    'strtolower' => 1,
                                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                            ),
                            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                            'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                            'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                            'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                            'autoUpdate' => 1,
                            'expireDays' => 180,
                    ),
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_mystuff_collection[action]',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_mystuff_collection[controller]',
            ),


        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

# 404 Errorhandling

if (preg_match('/\/ch\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 1) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/ch/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/gb\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 2) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/uk/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/au\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 3) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/au/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/at\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 4) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/at/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/ca\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 5) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/ca/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/hr\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 6) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/hr/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/cy\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 7) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/cy/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/fi\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 10) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/fi/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/de\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 12) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/de/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/hu\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 13) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/hu/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/it\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 15) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/it/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/sa\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 16) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/sa/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/nl\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 18) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/nl/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/no\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 19) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/no/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/sg\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 20) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/sg/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/es\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 23) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/es/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/se\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 24) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/se/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/tr\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 26) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/tr/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/ae\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 27) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/ae/404/';
} else if (preg_match('/\/us\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_GET['L'] == 28) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/us/404/';
} else  {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/uk/404/';
}
```

My Typoscript for languages (to keep it small just for german and dutch, other languages are similar):

```
config {
  sys_language_uid = 0
  language = en
  locale_all = en_EN

}

[globalVar = GP:L = 12]
config {
  sys_language_uid = 12
  language = de
  locale_all = de_DE
  sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
  sys_language_mode = strict
}
  lib.language.value = 12

plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 12
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.languageUid = 12
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 18]
config {
  sys_language_uid = 18
  language = nl
  locale_all = nl_NL
  sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
  sys_language_mode = strict
}
  lib.language.value = 18

  plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 18
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.languageUid = 18
[global]
```

Unfortunately I am not sure how to reproduce this. I found out that some links in dutch always are right, while others are not.

My guess is: The page got translated and called, but the title wasnt changed then, so that the default-title was taken and that it got cached. Then the title got changed and the new URL got cached too. This would fit with the fact, that the "wrong" URLs do not work while logged in in the backend, cause as far as I know while you are logged the system will not use some caches.

(While I wrote this question I really think now my guess is true, can someone confirm?)

Is there some way to priorice one URL over another? I would like to see the newer/the current title, URL will be taken.

Just delete it at this time is unfortunately not possible, as we send out some of the "wrong" URLs in a newsletter and it would be nice if we could keep the "wrong" URLs for a month, but use only the current URL for Menus/Links.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Check your sitemap and robots.txt, in some cases those are wrong and robots visiting website will cache pages with wrong combinations of pages and languages. Also from what you write, it seems like f:link.page always generates correct URL, since it always generates only: \index.php?id=123&L=12 but then realurl transforms it to the URL you call wrong.

Comment: @JozefSpisiak Yes f:link.page generates the right URL, but realurl sometimes takes the wrong (old) cache (at least that is what I assume.